# Calculate distance between sparse vectors

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the cosine (scipy) distance between two vectors. I originally have a DataFrame with the '**category**' and **value** for each **person**.

I want to calculate the distance between *persons* using the vector with values *value* indexed by *category*.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

d = {'person' : ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4'],
 'category' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'D'],
  'value' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

  category person  value
0        A      1      1
1        B      1      1
2        C      1      1
3        B      2      1
4        D      2      1
5        E      3      1
6        F      3      1
7        F      4      1
8        D      4      1
```

I can do this by creating a pivot table like this:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['person'], columns='category', values='value', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

index person  A  B  C  D  E  F
0          1  1  1  1  0  0  0
1          2  0  1  0  1  0  0
2          3  0  0  0  0  1  1
3          4  0  0  0  1  0  1
```

However, I do not want to do this (I am dealing with big vectors so pd.pivot_table can take a while).

How can I do this using the original 'sparse' format in df?

Comment: Whence and how are you loading the data?

Comment: The raw data is coming from csv or txr files so I create the raw dataframe using pd.read_csv

Comment: Can you provide a __reproducible__ sample with a column(s) of sparse dtype?

Comment: Your data comes from CSV files.  Quite likely the single slowest part of your loading process is simply loading the data from this inefficient format.  If it were me I would just do the transform at load time.

Comment: @MaxU Maybe I should not say that I have a 'sparse vector'. What I have is what I show in df.

Comment: @JohnZwinck pd.pivot_table can take a few minutes actually. That is why I want to avoid doing it. Most of the elements are going to be zero anyway so I think it is more efficient to compute the distance without creating vectors of the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [30]: pd.crosstab(df.person, df.category).reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
Out[30]:
  person  A  B  C  D  E  F
0      1  1  1  1  0  0  0
1      2  0  1  0  1  0  0
2      3  0  0  0  0  1  1
3      4  0  0  0  1  0  1
```